# Adding user Without password in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have installed Postgres `v12` on Windows Machine. I have looked documentation of Postgres, but they are using command-line tools commands as

`create user <username>` etc,

I am using these commands but didn't get Logged into it.It says

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

[image: Sql Shell]

How Can I add a user in Postgres psql shell without a password ?

Comment: An alternative solution is to set a password with `\password user1`.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to be prompted for a password, you will need to have provision for that user in your `pg_hba.conf` file.

For example:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all             user1           0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

The first line beginning with "host" uses the method of "trust" which means the user will go unchallenged.  You can change any of the other parameters as you see fit, but as long as they hit this rule first, other rules won't insist on a password.  Once you make this change, you'll need to reload the service for it to take effect.

Comment: In which directory pg_hba.conf  will be located ?

Comment: Depends on how your distro is set up, but it's typically in the data directory alongside `posgresql.conf`.  On some distros it can be found under `/etc/postgresql/`.  If you want to know where this is, you can run `SHOW data_directory;` in psql.

Comment: I've updated the example to illustrate the change you need to make.  The first line with "host" at the beginning is the line you would need to add.  The lines following need to remain in the file unedited in this instance.  Note that the example shows a method of "trust" at the end of the line, which means don't prompt for a password.  The line that shows "md5" means that it will prompt for a password (using an md5 hash to send it to the database).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `.pgpass` file to automatically provide the password to the postgresql commands.

Create a file `~/.pgpass` with the following line:

```
localhost:*:*:username:
```

This refers to `hostname:port:database:username:password` if you want to make it more specific.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11, it appears that connections from localhost are defaulting to Ipv6 addressing, so you will want a line like this:

```
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             user1             ::1/128                 trust
```